# How is , a.k.a Catamite, the Etruscan form of Gadymedes?

Tags: greek, comparative, roman, etymology

It's obvious why  is [catamite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catamite), but not how the Etruscans got it from "Gadymedes".

Is it just "We know they're the same character / name, but we dunno how the Etruscans got there"?

Comment: Maybe a language SE would be more adequate?

Comment: @MardukTrimegistus - I thought so, but I think I've used them enough such that I know that no, we don't have an language SE that allows general etymology?

Comment: You can ask over on [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

#### Regular Sound Change

It's been a while since I looked at Etruscan, but two things that stuck out was that the language doesn't seem to get along well with voiced stops (like [g] and [d]), and also that they tended to reduce the number of vowels & syllables in their words. A quick review of the Wikipedia list of [Etruscan mythological figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Etruscan_mythological_figures) shows that this is a regular occurrence:

Achmemrun  < Gk Agamemnon
Aitas  <  Gk Hades
Catmite  <  Gk Gadymedes :: of note, Latin borrowed this name as Catamitus and also Ganymedes from Greek
Metus  <  Gk Medusa
Rathmtr  <  Gk Rhadamanthys
Satre  <  Lat Saturnus